# php yii framework :: $content is not found

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

There is a variable in my code called `$contant`. But I am not able to find the variable anywhere.

This is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial("/site/_navigation",null,true,false); ?>

<div class="content">

    <?php echo $content; ?>

</div> 

<?php echo $this->renderPartial("/site/_footer",null,true,false); ?>
```

Comment: I guess this happens in your template file. So `$content` is a variable generated in your model and most likely defined in an array á la `$vars['content']`.

Comment: show your action in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$content` stores the rendering result of the view. For example, a layout may contain a header and a footer, and embed the view in between, like this:

```
......header code here......
<?php 
    echo $content; 
?>
......footer code here......
```

$content is the part of the Layout in Yii. Layout is a special view that is used to decorate views. It usually contains parts of a user interface that are common among several views. Layout is implicitly applied when calling `render()`. So Here is your code.

```
// Your Header Here
<?php echo $this->renderPartial("/site/_navigation",null,true,false); ?>

<div class="content">
    // Your content goes here
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div> 

//Your Footer Here
<?php echo $this->renderPartial("/site/_footer",null,true,false); ?>
```

By default, the view script `protected/views/layouts/main.php` is used as the layout. This can be customized by changing either `CWebApplication::layout` or `CController::layout`.

To render a view without applying any layout, call `renderPartial()` instead.

Read the [**Layout**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#layout) section in Yii.

Read the **[Full Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/index)** to Yii.